# MathJax with html background and font color issue

Tags: latex, mathjax, mathml

Following html file does not display a `LaTex` expression (a fraction a/b) in display mode when using html background and font color. Also, in inline mode, with background and font color the denominator cuts the lower edge a quite a bit (as shown in image below). Thank you for giving us MathJax as it helps us so much in many areas of our work.

**Html file**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
A \(\frac{a}{b}\) fraction in inline mode
<br/>
A\[\frac{a}{b}\] fraction in display mode
<br/>
A <span style='color:white;background:black'>\(\frac{a}{b}\)</span> fraction in inline mode with black background and white font
<br/>
A <span style='color:white;background:black'>\[\frac{a}{b}\]</span> fraction in display mode with black background and white font. This one is not displaying fraction.

</body>
</html>
```

**Display on both IE 11 and Chrome**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by changing `<span style='color:white;background:black'>` to `<span class='inverted'>` and adding this CSS code to your style sheet

```
.inverted .math {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

You might also find [CSS Style Objects](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/reference/CSS-styles.html) useful.

**EDIT:**

One way to add this CSS is to change the code inside your `<head>` tag like this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .inverted .math {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style> 
</head>
```

I would also strongly recommend you to learn the basics of CSS (at least), [w3schools tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) might be really helpful.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I added your css code inside `<style>...</style>`  in the `<head>` tag in my Html file above.

Comment: @nam There are other ways to do this and quite many problems you might encounter with CSS, to avoid wasting time do consider reading tutorials. Good luck.